# Считать строку начиная с.. до

Tags: python

Нужно считать строки, начиная со 2ого элемента до конца строки

```
myfile=open("myfile.txt")

for line in myfile:
    n= line.split()[0][:2]
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myfile=open("myfile.txt")

for line in myfile:
     n= line[1:].rstrip()
     print(n)
```

Comment: а если с 3-его?

Comment: @Jevgewa  n= line.split()[0][2:]

Comment: можете прокомментировать? что здесь 0 значит и 2:

Comment: и в каких случаях двоеточие ставится перед цифрой ?

Comment: @Jevgewa начинать с 2 и до конца, а [0] это первый элемент в списке

Comment: @Jevgewa лучше  ***n= line[1:].rstrip()***